# how to locate source code of page in admin panel

Tags: code-generation, locations, source

how can i locate any exact source code page to change content .
for example how can i locate
Customers  --> All Customers --> then select one customer then press edit --> how can i found this page to remove the table content ?

[image]

Thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

1- Login to the admin Panel

2- Click on **Store**

3- Click on **Configuration**

4- Click on **Advanced** Tab

5- Click on **Developer**

6- Click on **Debug**

7- Select yes to **Enable Template Path Hints for Admin**

8- Also Click on **Template Settings**

9- Select Yes to **Allow Symlinks**

10- Flush Cache and Reload the Page

In this way you can navigate to the template files and can further get the controller, blocks, helper etc used in the template file

Comment: i don't have developer option under Advanced 
only admin - system - lazy loading